# Why doesn't "several formal events" work in this context?

Tags: word-choice

> 1.
>   The Fern Lake Community Center is an entirely volunteer-run organization serving the Fern Lake community. Popularly known among locals as "The Fern," our center offers high-quality after-school care for local children of working parents. We also host educational programs for all ages in our buildings on Quentin Street. These include classes in dancing and painting.
>
> In addition, **the community center offers several ㅡㅡㅡㅡ events** throughout the year. The largest and most famous is our annual Fern Fair. All residents are invited to join us on April 12 this year on the Broad Street Pier to enjoy the area's best food, crafts, and musical performances while savoring the cool spring breeze.

In this blank, the answer is 'outdoor' because 'In addition' functions by contrasting 'in our buildings' and 'on the Broad street Pier'. and I understand it.

but I was wondering why 'formal' can't count in that blank...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first question

> the community center offers several **formal** events

has the meaning people would be dressed *formally*, for example "[***a ball***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_(dance_party))" is a formal event, however the description of your community center indicates it is not formal but more casual.

> the community center offers several **exciting** events

might be a better choice.

Comment: 감사합니다ㅅㅅㅅㅅㅅㅅㅅㅅㅅㅅ

Comment: 천만에요ㅅㅅㅅㅅㅅㅅㅅㅅㅅㅅㅅ